# how to convert ascii text art into UIImage on iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimage, ascii, screenshot

I am taking image as an input and converting it into ascii(actually two formats-a simple character string and an html page out of it). The approach I am using to save this ascii text as UIImage is to display the *text* in UIWebView and take its screenshot programatically and save it. My problem here is that when I take the screenshot it is only able to capture and save the visible part of the scrollable view.

My question is that is there an alternate way of saving the ascii as UIImage other then going the UIWebView approach. If I have to use UIWebView could someone suggest how to go about re-scrolling and taking the second(and maybe more) screenshot.

with regards,
Rol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `drawAtPoint:withAttributes` method to draw string objects in a view. Then convert the content of the view into an UIImage object as discussed [here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/getting-contents-of-uiview-as-uiimage.html).

Comment: thanks for the help. I tried following your suggestion but kind of lost here. All reference code I found were for cocoa. Are you sure drawAtPoint:withAttributes works for iphone too?

Comment: You can find its usage on NSString on the sample project 'AdvancedTableViewCell' [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AdvancedTableViewCells/Introduction/Intro.html). Look `CompositeSubviewBasedApplicationCell.m`, line 80